# calculating total rows from one table with 2 level child

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table of "galleries" and one for "images".. the galleries table goes like this..

```
gal_id|name
```

and images is like

```
img_id|gal_id|name
```

now I have say 20 galleries, and I want to display total number of images in each gallery, so I want to use one query to return the array with total images in each gallery something like this

```
Gallery A (Total Images : 23)
Gallery B (Total Images : 33)
Gallery C (Total Images : 523)
Gallery D (Total Images : 25)
```

What would be the best approach to do this, I dont want to put the query in loop it will put load on server, please advise..

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rudimentary [aggregate `COUNT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) grouped by gallery `name`.

Importantly, this must use a **`LEFT JOIN`** to be sure that galleries having no images return a zero count rather than returning no row at all.

```
SELECT
  galleries.name,
  COUNT(images.img_id) AS total_images
FROM 
  galleries
  /* LEFT JOIN will ensure empty galleries are listed */
  LEFT JOIN images  ON galleries.gal_id = images.gal_id
GROUP BY galleries.name
/* Sort by descending total_images */
ORDER BY total_images DESC
```

#### Update after comment

```
SELECT
  galleries.name,
  COUNT(images.img_id) AS total_images,
  /* Differentiate between downloadable/not downloadable with a SUM(CASE) */
  /* It converts each into a zero or one and then sums up the values */
  SUM(CASE WHEN downloadable = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS downloadable,
  SUM(CASE WHEN downloadable = 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS not_downloadable
FROM 
  galleries
  /* LEFT JOIN will ensure empty galleries are listed */
  LEFT JOIN images  ON galleries.gal_id = images.gal_id
GROUP BY galleries.name
/* Sort by descending total_images */
ORDER BY total_images DESC
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, I tried to use ORDER by maximum number of images at the top, but ORDER BY total_images DESC failed, can you please help on this as well.. thanks

Comment: `ORDER BY total_images DESC` should work fine.  Cribbing from Mahmoud's demo -here's mine with the order applied. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab2a3/1

Comment: ooope my fault, I didn't notice I applied LIMIT and was using ORDER BY after that. Worked :) Thank you..

Comment: hi Michael again, I have run into another challenge now.. I have a field in IMAGE table called

downloadable  ENUM('Y','N') default 'N'

now I have to display those galleries twice with under "Downloadable" and "Not Downloadable", but with the code abovem it only lists one time I also tried something like this after WHERE clause..

AND (images.downloadable='Y' OR images.downloadable='N')

and then in the while() loop I tried to differentiate with IF to find out, but when I printed the whole row array it is showing one "downloadable" for whole gallery.. can we do this all..

Comment: @user1718343 See addition above.  Generally though, for this kind of thing, you should usually ask a new question when it goes outside the original scope.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I am sorry for posting within the same question, I am new here, last time I asked one question and everyone negatively reported by saying its not a genuine question, then my account got blocked, I was afraid if I ask another question related to this one, someone will come saying "why you posted another question related to old question", I again appologize if it was wrong..

Comment: I am sure your code will be 110% correct but I am getting the following error:

1064 : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SUM(CASE WHEN downloadable = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS downloadable' at line 4

regards

Comment: @user1718343 Was missing a comma after `total_images`

Comment: thanks Michael :) so nice of you, I will play with your code now and definitely start a new question this time if I need help. thanks

Comment: @user1718343 The trick to asking a new question is to be sure to identify new areas that are giving you trouble, as in this case the summing up of the Y/N is legitimately a different issue than your original question.  Often though (and these will get downvoted & closed) users will post the same block of code over and over, asking for little incremental changes and bugfixes. That really irritates the community because it shows that nothing has been learned along the way.  If you point out what you have learned already and where you got stuck later in a new question, it would be better received

Answer (score 3):

Use `COUNT` with a `GROUP BY` like so:

```
SELECT g.name 'Gallery Name', COUNT(i.img_id) 'Total Images'
FROM galleries g
INNER JOIN images i ON g.gal_id = i.gal_id
GROUP BY g.name
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d53f/3)

Comment: thanks Mahmoud, it was nice of you. First I tried the top one and it worked for me, I just wanted to thank you for you effort. much appreciated